# c# linq get results by filters and discard string empty

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have the following Linq expression:

```
results = results.Where(r => r.FathersLast.StartsWith(fathersLast) && (mothersLast != string.Empty && r.MothersLast.StartsWith(mothersLast))).ToList();
```

What I want to do is:

If **mothersLast** variable is a string.empty, then don't consider filtering by r.MothersLast otherwise filter by r.MothersLast.StartWith(mothersLast).

Any clue on how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below :

```
results = results.Where(r => r.FathersLast.StartsWith(fathersLast) && (mothersLast == string.Empty || r.MothersLast.StartsWith(mothersLast))).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, *every string* starts with `string.Empty`, so if `mothersLast == string.Empty`  you don't have to do any more work. Just simplify your query to:

```
results = results.Where(r => r.FathersLast.StartsWith(fathersLast) && 
                             r.MothersLast.StartsWith(mothersLast)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
results = results
  .Where(r => 
    r.FathersLast.StartsWith(fathersLast) &&
    (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mothersLast) || r.MothersLast.StartsWith(mothersLast)))
  .ToList();
```

The operative change is the following

```
 (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mothersLast) || r.MothersLast.StartsWith(mothersLast))
```

This will only check for the match of `mothersLast` is a string of length greater than 0

Answer (score 1):

Why check the value of `mothersLast` for `string.Empty` repeatedly? I don't see anything that would modify it's value, so just check it once before running the LINQ statement:

```
if (mothersLast != string.Empty)
    results = results.Where(r => r.FathersLast.StartsWith(fathersLast) &&
                                 r.MothersLast.StartsWith(mothersLast)).ToList();
```

This is basically what you're code is doing, whether you intended it to or not.

It seems like you want to filter by fathersLast no matter what. In that case, for readability, just break it into two statements:

```
results = results.Where(r => r.FathersLast.StartsWith(fathersLast)).ToList();
if (mothersLast != string.Empty)
    r.MothersLast.StartsWith(mothersLast)).ToList();
```

Casting to `ToList()` twice is unnecessary, and you could code around that, but I'll leave that up to you based on how big the list is.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = results.Where(r => r.FathersLast.StartsWith(fathersLast) && (mothersLast == string.Empty || r.MothersLast.StartsWith(mothersLast))).ToList();
```